# VBA - When to specify ActiveWorkbook

Tags: vba, excel

When writing VBA code, if you know you're going to be operating in the same workbook and on a certain worksheet, should you specify `ActiveWorkbook` for the workbook objects in your code there?
Example:
`ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1")`
vs
`Range("$A$1")`
Above code assumes you are working off of Sheet1 through local macros(under Sheet1 object in VBA).

Comment: No - if you know you are going to be operating in the same workbook you should use ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") to qualify the sheet object. It is possible to call a macro in an inactive workbook

Comment: @Mukul215 - You need to `Set` a worksheet object.

Comment: The only time I habitually use ActiveWorkbook is when I copy a worksheet to an undisclosed location thereby creating a copy of the worksheet in a new untitled workbook. ActiveWorkbook is pretty much necessary at that point to identify the newly created workbook/worksheet so it can be named and saved.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification, the fact that 'Range("$A$1")' worked like the previous statement suggested an implicit object called it; I just didn't want to assume which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than using `ActiveWorkbook` in most situations is using `WorkBooks("Book1")`  This is more specific and robust and I believe faster to execute than activating a workbook and then pointing to it when referencing ranges.

The VBA will default to the last active workbook if you do not designate one when using lines of code like `Range("A1")`  So if you are working in just one workbook it is not necessary since the last active workbook should always be the workbook you want the code to execute in.  I typically only designate sheets and ranges when I'm working in a single workbook since it is a little redundant to tell excel to select the active workbook when it already does by default in the absence of a specific workbook designation.

Just make sure that you will be running the macro from the open workbook that you want the code to execute in.

Including a workbook designation will never hurt and it will make your code more robust.  But if you will only ever have the code execute in a single workbook it is not necessary.